# The difference of handling signed overflow of int and short

Tags: c++

Signed overflow of `int` is undefined behavior:

```
int a = INT_MAX;
a += 1; // Undefined Behavior
```

The same operation of `short` is implementation defined (if `short` is smaller than `int`):

```
short a = SHRT_MAX;
a += 1; // Implementation defined
```

It is implementation defined, because `a` first gets promoted to `int` (a usually wider type than `short`), and after the addition, the result gets converted to `short`, which is implementation defined, if the value cannot be represented in a `short`.

Am I right on this? If yes, why is there the difference? Wouldn't it be logical that both are undefined behavior or implementation defined?